# initiating a program that has more user privilages in restricted user

Tags: impersonation, file-permissions

I have users with limited access granted to one of my hard drives. Those users are not given the permittion to delete the files in that drive. but I have a application that should allow those users to delete files in the above mentioned drive.

1) How can I do this?

2) When a low priviliaged user loged to my application, can I write a hidden thread/ program that that gives high privileged user authority (only for this application), as in impersonating another user, so that he will be abel to delete files via this appliction in the restricted hard disk?

Thanks

Comment: I would not recommend it, but yes it can be done. Which programming language?

Comment: The program is in C# and Operating System is Windows.
Can u suggest me some ways?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS you can do various things.

In a UNIX like environment you can write a program and use setuid or setguid so that it runs with priviledges of another (more priviledged) user.

Alternatively in Windows or UNIX you can run a service as the more priviledged user and let it take requests from other users/processes to carry out the operation on their behalf. You'd have to look into ways to communicate with the service.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to write a service which exposes a named pipe, and create a client application which talks to the pipe and issues instructions to your service. The service runs under LocalSystem or a nominated higher-privilege account, and carries out instructions from the app running under a user account with lower privilege. You'd need some sort of handshake to establish bona-fides when you connect to the pipe, but it's not hard to do. You could use WCF instead of pipes, but I don't think you get much advantage from that in this scenario.